# Как с помощью htaccess запретить переход на сайт через плохие запросы в браузере?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, ddos, трафик, яндекс-метрика

В яндекс-метрике(в вебвизоре) показывается что на сайт заходят юзеры через разные запросы в браузере по типу: секс, наркотики и тд. Полагаю, что это накрутка плохого трафика. Таких нежелательных запросов всего 3 через которые заходят десятки юзеров на сайт. Я узнал, что можно через htaccess запретить данные выражения. пробовал следующий код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все равно не работает
Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, уверен, я что-то не правильно делаю(в коде на картинке)
Заранее большое спасибо за помощь !

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Есть ли какой-нибудь гениратор, чтобы можно было вставить запрос и он преобразовал это в код для htaccess ?